# What is the sunnah in wearing slippers?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, sunnah

- How did our Prophet(PBUH) wear his slippers/shoes?
- Is there any specific dua for that?

Post some references for your answer.

Comment: Of course, start with the right one :)

Answer (score 1):

The sunnah of putting on shoes is put on the right first than the left, and when taking off take out the left foot first than the right, [Source](http://sunnah.com/urn/2117580).  One should also not wear one shoes on a foot, either put on both shoes or don't put on anything at all.

> لاَ يَمْشِي أَحَدُكُمْ فِي نَعْلٍ وَاحِدَةٍ لِيُحْفِهِمَا جَمِيعًا،
> أَوْ لِيَنْعَلْهُمَا جَمِيعًا
>
> None of you should walk, wearing one shoe only; he should either put
> on both shoes or put on no shoes whatsoever
>
> Saheeh Bukari Book 77, Hadith 73

As for a dua when putting them on, I do not know.

Comment: is there any dua for that?

Comment: @Muslim I do not know, I am not familiar with such a thing.  There is a hadith in Tirmidhi (if I am not mistaken) giving a dua for putting on cloths but I currently can't find it and I am unsure of it's authenticity.

Comment: I think wearing clothes is differ from wearing shoes

Comment: @Muslim yes I believe so too.

Comment: @AlUmmatمجاهد Also, it is nice to mention that the Prophet (salallahu alayhi wassalam) advised us to wear the shoes while sitting and not standing. http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=85527